# Performance: Array.removeAll vs `= []`

Tags: swift, performance, memory, collections

Is there a difference in performance computationally and/or memory-wise between Swift `Array`/`Dictionary` primitive functions `removeAll` and `init`? Basically, I am asking, what are the pros and cons to resetting a mutable collection in Swift, and is one considered the recommended way to empty an `Array`/`Dictionary`?

```
// Scenario A
var myArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
myArray.removeAll()

// Scenario B
myArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
myArray = []
```

Comment: Do you actually have a performance issue using one or the other or is this just out of curiosity? Create a test app and test the performance. Be sure your tests are run using an optimized build running on a real device.

Comment: @maddy just curious, and not exactly an expert on running and conducting my own performance tests

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The performance difference should not be significant as they do largely the same thing. Let’s look at [the source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/ad50a39b120343f4827edb0a5a7013bb586306a6/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L1255):

```
/// Removes all elements from the array.
///
/// - Parameter keepCapacity: Pass `true` to keep the existing capacity of
///   the array after removing its elements. The default value is
///   `false`.
///
/// - Complexity: O(*n*), where *n* is the length of the array.
@inlinable
public mutating func removeAll(keepingCapacity keepCapacity: Bool = false) {
  if !keepCapacity {
    _buffer = _Buffer()
  }
  else {
    self.replaceSubrange(indices, with: EmptyCollection())
  }
}
```

There are [several other implementations of this method](https://github.com/apple/swift/search?q=%22func%20removeAll%28keepingCapacity%22&unscoped_q=%22func%20removeAll%28keepingCapacity%22) for different types, but the pattern is always the same. If `removeAll` parameter `keepCapacity` is `false`, just reinitialize it, largely equivalent to saying `myArray = []`.

So, the only question is whether you want to preserve the capacity of the array after removing its elements or not (which you might do if you’re emptying a large array and about to repopulate with another array of the same size).

---

If you want, benchmark it. For example, add "Unit Test” target to your project, bumping up the number of iterations high enough to make the duration observable:

```
class MyAppTests: XCTestCase {

    func testPerformanceRemoveAll() {
        var countTotal = 0
        var myArray: [Int] = []

        self.measure {
            for _ in 0 ..< 1_000_000 {
                myArray = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1_000)
                myArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                countTotal += myArray.count
            }
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(countTotal, 0)
    }

    func testPerformanceReinitialize() {
        var countTotal = 0
        var myArray: [Int] = []

        self.measure {
            for _ in 0 ..< 1_000_000 {
                myArray = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1_000)
                myArray = []
                countTotal += myArray.count
            }
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(countTotal, 0)
    }

}
```

With the following results:

```
Test Case '-[MyAppTests.MyAppTests testPerformanceReinitialize]' started.
/.../MyApp/MyAppTests/MyAppTests.swift:41: Test Case '-[MyAppTests.MyAppTests testPerformanceReinitialize]' measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.221, relative standard deviation: 6.559%, values: [0.264467, 0.216076, 0.216146, 0.216040, 0.216014, 0.216426, 0.216374, 0.215876, 0.216272, 0.216152], performanceMetricID:com.apple.XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.100, maxStandardDeviation: 0.100
Test Case '-[MyAppTests.MyAppTests testPerformanceReinitialize]' passed (2.646 seconds).

Test Case '-[MyAppTests.MyAppTests testPerformanceRemoveAll]' started.
/.../MyApp/MyAppTests/MyAppTests.swift:26: Test Case '-[MyAppTests.MyAppTests testPerformanceRemoveAll]' measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.235, relative standard deviation: 6.712%, values: [0.282223, 0.229732, 0.229601, 0.229624, 0.229584, 0.229652, 0.229695, 0.229729, 0.229702, 0.229659], performanceMetricID:com.apple.XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.100, maxStandardDeviation: 0.100
Test Case '-[MyAppTests.MyAppTests testPerformanceRemoveAll]' passed (2.602 seconds).
```

[image]

By the way, if you’re wondering about why I’m adding the totals after emptying the array, I’m just trying to make sure that I actually use the array after emptying it to ensure that the optimizer doesn’t optimize out the code doing the emptying. It’s not necessary in this case, but is prudent.

I also did the test with `Int` instead of `String`, as I’m not curious about the `String` overhead, but rather trying to focus on the `Array` behavior.

Bottom line, the performance difference was largely indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs `removeAll()`

> is a Complexity: O(n), where n is the length of the array.

So it would vary in speed based on the size of the array. As others mentioned though it would be premature optimization to pick one over the other at the expense of readability.

Comment: By the way, that tells us about how performance of `removeAll` varies based upon size of the array, but it doesn’t tell us about the performance of `removeAll` vs `init`.